# End date or inactive of a Cognito form

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to set an end date that the form will be available for submission?

I would like to have a deadline for completion and submission of the form and would like to set the form to automatically become inactive—although I would like to keep it in my forms list so I can access the submissions and re-use the form in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I am a developer for Cognito Forms. This is a feature we are adding in the next release, which is currently in testing. Here is an example of the feature on the Form Settings Menu.

[image]

We will be sending out an email to all Cognito users when the new features become available.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas!  Do you have an estimated date for release?